# Calling a props function from constructor vs componentDidMount?

Tags: reactjs

In my react component, there is a function in props that I want to call at the time of component rendering which can be called from either constructor or componentDidMount() function. Mostly I don't see calling function from constructor in general in react project that I saw so far? But in my case, it doesn't matter where I call it (constructor vs componentDidMount(). So, I was thinking to call from constructor just before the component is rendered.

Is there any downside in calling the function from constructor?

Call from constructor looks like below:

```
export class XYZ extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
    };

    this.props.updateId(0);
  }


  .....

  render() {
      ......
  }
}
```

Call from componentDidMount() looks like below:

```
export class XYZ extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      selectedItems: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.updateId(0);
  }


  .....

  render() {
      ......
  }
}
```

Edit:
updateId function is defined in parent component where it just pass the Id 0 to parent component and then parent component sets it in state which is used to show something.

Comment: It's always advisable to have it in the `componentDidMount` than the constructor, once component is loaded. At the moment, theoretically, we can't see any issues.

Comment: @PraveenKumarPurushothaman Thanks for your answer. Why is it advisable to have it in componentDidMount?

Comment: What if something is there that requires the contents of the component? When both the functions do the same thing, it's always wise to use the CDM because you have access to the loaded elements.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call `Parent function` before rendering the `Child Component` then you call it in `Constructor`, but if you need to call it after `Child Component` rendered, then You can use `componentDidMount` method.

Note that, if you gonna switch to react Hooks then it would be useful to call parent functions conditionally or inside `useEffect`.